# Gcloud cannot detect network connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil, esxi

I have internet connection on the ESXi server and I want to copy everything to GCP storage. But Gcloud couldn't authenticate. It looks like it can't reach the gloud login servers.

I'm not if the esxi provider has blocked GCP IP's but is there a way I can verify? Do we know which IP or DNS address it tries to connect?

Could this be a different issue? I tried disable ipv6 and was hoping it would work.

```
./gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

    ERROR: There was a problem with web authentication.
    ERROR: (gcloud.auth.login) Could not reach the login server. A potential cause of this could be because you are behind a proxy. Please set the environment variables HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY to the address of the proxy in the format "protocol://address:port" (without quotes) and try again.
    Example: HTTPS_PROXY=https://192.168.0.1:8080
```

Comment: It's a network issue. All depends on your network configuration/architecture. Try to ping a Google api (`ping storage.googleapis.com` for instance)

Comment: I can ping storage.googleapis.com. But something is preventing gcloud to auth

Comment: Can you perform a `nslookup www.google.com`? a `curl https://www.google.com`?

Comment: Yea nslookup works fine. Don't have curl but I used wget to pull google.com index page.

Comment: Hmm, DNS, ICMP and HTTPS are reachable. Strange that your gcloud init doesn't work. Maybe because you have a proxy , but I can't help you on this!

Answer (score 0):

You might get more information from:

```
gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Are you running behind a proxy?  If so, you need to set proxy settings for gcloud: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings